# Como retornar diferença após execução de update no Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Alguém sabe me informar como faço para retornar apenas as campos e valores alterados em um update no laravel?

ex: uma tabela que contém um campo nome com valor João, vamos supor que eu altero esse campo para João carlos.
Gostaria de saber como faço para retornar o campo alterado após o update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você fazer isso você pode fazer uma "pequena manobra" utilizando o método `getDirty`.

Esse método serve para trazer os atributos que foram alterados, antes da atualização do model.

Então, você poderia fazer assim:

```
   $usuario = Usuario::find($id);

   $usuario->fill(Input::all());

   $campos_alterados = $usuario->getDirty();

   $usuario->save();
```

Creio que esse exemplo seja a forma mais simples. Mas também podemos considerar utilizar alguns recursos do OOP do PHP.

Por exemplo, podemos clonar o objeto antes de alterá-lo e comparar as diferenças:

```
 $usuario = Usuario::find($id);

 $clone = clone $usuario;

 $usuario->update($inputs);

 array_diff($clone->getAttributes(), $usuario->getAttributes());
```